# Unix sed can't read. peculiar issue when using a variable

Tags: bash, unix, shell, script, sed

One line in a control file looks like this:
1039 ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt
So using space as a delimiter, I am cutting and assigning the filename alone to a variable like below:
file=`echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f2`

and then I use sed:
sed -i 1d "$targetDir"/"$file"

but in the log I am getting the below error:
I did an echo as well to confirm if the file exists. As you can see, the file exists. but sed says no such file or directory.

- file=$'ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt\r'
- echo '/u/applic/data/hdfs1/etl_grmacw/ACDW/source/ZA/ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt exists'
  /u/applic/data/hdfs1/etl_grmacw/ACDW/source/ZA/ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt exists
- sed -i 1d $'/u/applic/data/hdfs1/etl_grmacw/ACDW/source/ZA/ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt\r'
  sed: can't read /u/applic/data/hdfs1/etl_grmacw/ACDW/source/ZA/ZA_BKPF_20170725103534.txt: No such file or directory

Is someone familiar with the $'string\r'. why is this happening to my variables. Is that the problem or something else? Can someone help me pls !
Thanks,
Hari G

Comment: It looks as though your control file is in Windows format. The `$'...'` format is just being used for reporting purposes, to show that there is a return (0x0D) character in the variable. You can use `tr` to filter it out,

Comment: ... or use `dos2unix` on the input file to clean it up.